# CSS Float divs sitting as block not as grid

Tags: css, css-float, liquid-layout

Please Check out the fiddle on http://jsfiddle.net/Qu63T/1/

What I want is The green div to float next to the blue one. and the `.block` divs to appear as a grid. I don't want to remove the `.m` div and float the `.block`s inside the container. What Can be done without specifying width of `.m`

No JavaScript Only CSS Solution

Comment: Don't get it. Green div is already floating next to the blue one?

Comment: can you explain it little more because right now it's confusing .

Comment: Its not `next` to Blue one. It has cleared its left. and it came down. I want the blue DIV to stay on left as a sidebar and the green div be a container of `block`s (in white border). and red div is the container of the whole story.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a a wrapper div, after .m and before .block and set his width:

```
<div class="m">
     <div class="wrapper">
           <div class="block">
           (...)
           </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Style:

```
.wrapper{
    width:100px;
}
```

Or you can add some padding in .m, so the blocks will line-break. But that's a wierd solution.

Answer (score 0):

as i understand your question that you want `floated div's` work like  `block` `div's`
your 
CSS:
    .

```
block{
        border: 1px solid white;
        float: left;
        display: inline-block;
        clear:left;
    }
```

check this http://jsfiddle.net/sandeep/Qu63T/6/

Answer (score 0):

Your best solution in this case would be to assume that "m" isnt floating, its just a padded div sitting inside a bigger container, and the blue div is living absolutely positioned, like this:

```
.c{
background-color: red;
display: block;
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
}
.l{
background-color: blue;

height: 40px;
width: 120px;
display: inline-block;
position: absolute;
left: 0;
right:0;
}
.m{
display: block;
position: relative;
margin-left: 125px;
}
.block{
border: 1px solid white;
float: left;
display: inline-block;
background-color: green;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Qu63T/7/

Comment: You are using absolute which is breaking the liquidness

Comment: absolute relative to parent only, it is liquid